# jQuery offset() returning null in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, null, offset

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="imagenes/user.png" width="32" height="32" alt="My Profile" title=""/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="imagenes/photo.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Photo Gallery" title=""/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="imagenes/bookmark.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Social Bookmarking Tools" title=""/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="imagenes/rss.png" width="32" height="32" alt="RSS" title=""/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="imagenes/search.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Search" title=""/></a></li>              
    <li class="selected"><a href="#"><img src="imagenes/setting.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Control Panel" title=""/></a></li>
</ul> 
<div id="box"><div class="head"></div></div></div>
```

And the following JS code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var style = 'easeOutExpo';
        var default_left = Math.round($('#menu li.selected').offset().left - $('#menu').offset().left);
        var default_top = $('#menu li.selected').height();
                ...
```

The problem that I'm having is that "$('#menu li.selected').offset()" is returning null in Chrome. I'm getting this error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null".
In Firefox 5.0 is working OK and I haven't tried in IE.

Thanks!

Comment: `$().offset()` only returns `null` when the element doesn't exist. I have tested your code in Chromium 14, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your HTML above, `<div id="menu">` does not have a closing tag.

Try adding one more `</div>` to the end of your HTML.

Comment: I didn't put the closing tag here but I have it in my code. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, well I've just tested this with Chrome 15 and jQuery 1.6.3 and `$('#menu li.selected').offset()` is working fine for me.